# Jenkins Bitbucket Deployment Issue with Linux VPS Server

Tags: git, jenkins, centos, bitbucket

I have a VPS server with CentOS and Jenkins installed. I can build with Bitbucket webhook via Jenkins, no problem.

I'm having the main problem with deployment. Since the Publish Over SSH plugin was removed, I wanted to use Publish Over FTP, but I had a problem with the shell.

Here is the shell command I use in Jenkins,

git ftp push --user USERNAME --passwd PASSWORD ftp://YOUR-FTP-SERVER-ADDRESS/path/to/website/

As a result (Jenkins console output) it gave this error,

git: 'ftp' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

As I understand this shell command is compatible with Ubuntu.

How can I make the easiest deployment with Jenkins on Linux CentOS? Is it possible to deploy via FTP or is there another way?

Comment: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: To expand a bit on @phd's comment: you must install git-ftp, it's not included with Git, it's a separate program. You'll need to do this on your Jenkins builders. Side note: don't use the [tag:linux] tag. It's supposed to be for Linux kernel internals and APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I installed git-ftp and the problem was solved. If there is an easy and safe way other than ftp I would like to test it.